# Move files to system partition

Tags: android

i'm tring to move an apk files from /data/app/ to /system/app. I wrote this code

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mv "+path+" "+"/system/app/);
```

Where path return sometime like /data/app/com.package.name-1.apk. This code doesn't work because the apk is not moved. Why? Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the return code from mv? That may give you a hint. process.exitValue();

Comment: Is your app a system app? How do you get root permissions?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `xml`?

Comment: Process as not yet terminated :-S

Comment: This will not work, because your application code is not itself running as root, and `mv` is not a setuid-root executable, so it won't  run as root unless run by root.  You'll need to make use of a root shim (`su` hack) if available on your device, or alter your overall approach and goals to something your device does support.  Also, mv does not necessarily work *across* partitions - technically that's a copy & delete rather than a "move", though some full-featured systems have an `mv` that will do that when access permissions allow.

Comment: Why ? Because you app does not have the right to write into `/system/app`

Comment: @user3289078 please accept an answer as correct if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify the contents of `/system` you need root permission. Root your device first and then you can move the file as follows:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo mv "+path+" "+"/system/app/);
```

Don't forget to set the appropriate attributes using `chmod` after moving.